# How to Resolve this - Enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, windows-services, windows-10

A long time back I developped a Windows service with c# 4.0 and also created a setup file with VS2010 for that app. I installed that app and it was running. someone removed that Windows service not properly like removing some entry from registry regarding that app and as a result that app name is not showing in ADD/Remove list and removed all files and folder from program files folder related to that Windows service.

So when I try to run the setup file for that win service to install it in my pc then I am getting the error message **Enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package** 
[image]

so guide me how could I again install that Windows service in my pc from that setup. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "Windows Installer cleanup uitlity" to be enormously helpful in situations like this. It's an abandoned project, but you can still get it by googling. You can use it to completely remove a program from your computer, after which it won't conflict with a new installation.
I found it here:

[www.majorgeeks.com](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_installer_cleanup_utility.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the file needed and provide the [un]installer with the download folder. And press `OK`. You can do it without interrupting the process. Do **not** use the `Windows Installer Cleanup Utility` It is not supported and extremely dangerous!

Comment: Alas, I've tried the method of providing the uninstaller with the missing file and it doesn't always work. Also, the file needed may not be available and then you're stuck. Why do you say the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility is extremely dangerous? I've occasionally used it for about a decade now and never had an issue.